# Visual Studio Natvis DisplayString Conditionals

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, natvis, xml-visualizer

Using Visual Studio 2017, I'm writing a Visualizer for some classes, but I'm running into issues with respect to the .natvis code readability.  I have a custom Array type, and I would like to display its members in the **Watch** window's **Value** field *directly* (as opposed to having to use the expand button).

**arrayType** is an enum defining the array type (Sparse, Empty, Dense, Singleton).  **numElems** is the number of entries in the array.  No need to focus on this data structure; it's just an example.  Here is my current natvis code:

```
<Type Name="MyProject::MyArray"
  <DisplayString Condition="numElems == 0">
    {arrayType,  en}
  </DisplayString>
  <DisplayString Condition="numElems == 1">
    {arrayType,  en} {*elems[0]}
  </DisplayString>
  <DisplayString Condition="numElems == 2">
    {arrayType,  en} {*elems[0]}, {*elems[1]}
  </DisplayString>
  <DisplayString Condition="numElems == 3">
    {arrayType,  en} {*elems[0]}, {*elems[1]}, {*elems[2]}
  </DisplayString>
  <DisplayString Condition="numElems >= 4">
    {arrayType,  en} {*elems[0]}, {*elems[1]}, {*elems[2]}, ...
  </DisplayString>
</Type>
```

[Notice that I have to repeat the same code over again (just adding an extra element to display).  I'm stopping at displaying 3 elements due to the code bloat.]

This would allow the **Watch Window** (within Visual Studio) to display objects in the following manner:

```
Name       Value
arr1       Sparse 5, 3                         ; numElems is 2
arr2       Empty                               ; numElems is 0
arr3       Singleton 1                         ; numElems is 1
arr4       Dense 58, 23, 1, ...                ; numElems is >= 4
```

Ideally, the DisplayString tag would allow conditionals within it.  I've tried the following workaround with C++ ternary operators, which did not work.

```
<Type Name="MyProject::Array"
  <DisplayString>
    {arrayType,  en} {(numElems >= 1) ? *elems[0] : ""}, {(numElems >= 2) ? *elems[1] : ""}, {(numElems >= 3) ? *elems[2] : ""}, {(numElems >= 4) ? "..." : ""}
  </DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Notice that in this code, I don't have to repeat the DisplayString tag multiple times over and duplicate code.  Maybe there is a way to provide an iterator within the DisplayString so as to list all the (variable amount of) elements?  I know about the ArrayItems tag, but that must be used within an Expand tag (again, I'm trying to display the array elements in the **Value** field (without having to click the expand button)).

Any suggestions?  Need clarification?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. What you already have is the only way to implement what you want (multiple DisplayStrings with conditionals).

Comment: Do you know of any plans to support conditionals within DisplayString?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use {elems,[numElems]}, which is simple but displays also the pointer.